# Pandas usecols and append from multiple dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am not sure what is the perfect way to achieve this:

I have multiple xlsx files and the customer_id column has different names in each file. Suppose the following example:

```
xlsx1: customer_id
xlsx2: ID
slsx3: client_ID
xlsx4: cus_id
xlsx5: consumer_number
xlsx6: customer_number
...etc
```

I want to read all the xlsx in a folder then just extract the customer id columns and append them to one dataframe.

What I did so far:

I created a list for every single expected customer_id column in the xlsx files:

```
customer_id = ["ID","customer_id","consumer_number","cus_id","client_ID"]
```

Then I read all the xlsx files in the folder:

```
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("./*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f, usecols = customer_id)
    all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
```

Here I got the error:

```
ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found:
```

I believe the usecols is matching all the columns names in the list in every xlsx file while I need to get the one column in xlsx files that matches the name.

Comment: if the column you want is still at the same place, like let's say the first column in each excel, then you can try `usecols = [0]` or something like this

Comment: Thanks Ben, the customer_id or similar columns have different locations in the xlsx files this why I want to find them by names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way is to read the full excel, `reindex` with the possible columns of ID in `customer_id` that will generate nan columns for the wrong names, then `dropna` them. Rename the column for later `concat`. Also don't use pandas `append` in a loop, `append` to a list and `concat` later, it is faster. so you get:

```
l = [] #use a list and concat later, faster than append in the loop
for f in glob.glob("./*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f).reindex(columns=customer_id).dropna(how='all', axis=1)
    df.columns = ["ID"] # to have only one column once concat
    l.append(df)
all_data  = pd.concat(l, ignore_index=True) # concat all data
```

Comment: Thanks Ben the code gave me the idea, I had two issues. The first I added `reindex( columns = customer_id)` as I got an error without columns.
The second is I removed `df.columns = "ID"` due to an error `Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'ID' was passed` so the new df will have multi-columns and I merged them with `all_data.fillna('').sum(axis=1)` to get final one column with all customer IDs.

Comment: @Mtaly right, one needed to specify that the `reindex` is for the columns and not for index (by default). and for the other error, `df.columns` has to be a list, not a string so it could be `df.columns = ["ID"]` if you are sure there is only one id column in each excel